# SQL query in Java throwing exception

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I have some Java pulling from an Access database. Here's the code doing the querying:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String filename = "C:/Development/tomcat/webapps/inquire/inquire.mdb";
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
database+= filename.trim() + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true}";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( database ,"","");
Statement s = con.createStatement();
s.execute ("SELECT manager FROM inquiries");
ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
```

Yes, there's a database named inquire.mdb at that location, with a table called 'inquiries' with a column named 'manager'

However, when the code executes I'm getting:

> java.sql.SQLException: Column not found

It's really weird because in another place this query works:

```
String theQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT manager FROM inquiries";
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String filename = "C:/Development/tomcat/webapps/inquire/inquire.mdb";
        String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
        database+= filename.trim() + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true}";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( database ,"","");
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        s.execute(theQuery);
        ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
```

Comment: Does the account your connecting with via JDBC have access to the database & table?

Comment: What is the value of theQuery in the second block?

Comment: Did you add this column to the database lately?

Comment: * the account has access

Comment: I just saw that the line defining theQuery got cut off, I just edited the question to show it. THe value is "SELECT DISTINCT manager FROM inquiries"

The column was one of the original columns when I created the database weeks ago. Note that the second query is using the same column, and it works. (which is key to understanding my question, so I'm sorry it was cut off earlier)

Comment: It appears that Java isn't closing the database correctly, because if I test the code, then try to rename the database through windows explorer it says it's in use. restarting the Java container frees it up.

I'm not sure why it wouldn't be closing though. I just looked through every class in the package, whether I thought it was being used or not, and they all have a con.close(); line after doing what I need done with the ResultSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, as is almost always the problem when I run into a programming issue, it was something stupid I did.

The problem was in the processing of the resultset, not the query. I had simplified the query but was still using other columns in the processing. So yeah, of course it couldn't find the column, I wasn't even pulling it with my query.

If I wasn't stupid I would have printed the whole frigging stacktrace, not just the stupid exception.

Then I could find what line it was actially dying at.

Then it takes just a few seconds to fix.

Instead of, you know, HOURS.